# Unexpected end of JSON input from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been working on a delete post functionality in my project. It all works fine in PHP, but now I'd like to do that in Ajax, to prevent the refresh and all.

Anyway, when I perform my ajax call, I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at Object.parse (native)
at n.parseJSON (http://localhost/imdstagram/public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:6401)
at Ab (http://localhost/imdstagram/public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:8347)
at z (http://localhost/imdstagram/public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:11804)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost/imdstagram/public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:15680)
```

It says that this error is on line 35, line 35 sends me to

```
console.log(error);
```

Anyway, to give you a better view, here is my Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".post__delete").on("click", function(e){
        var postDeleteID = $('.deleteID').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/deletePost.php", 
            type: "POST",             
            data: JSON.stringify(postDeleteID),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data)
            {

            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And my deletePost.php code:

```
<?php
    include_once("../classes/Post.class.php");
    session_start();
    $post = new Post();

    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $deletePostID = $_POST['deletePostID'];

        $post->deletePost($deletePostID);

        if($post->deletePost($deletePostID)){
            $status['delete'] = "success";
        } else {
            $status['delete'] = "failed";
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', true);
        echo json_encode($status);
    }

?>
```

I've tried many things like changing the dataType and contentType, but nothing seems to work out.

Comment: You've not provided the full exception message, nor the JSON that appears to be corrupt. We'll need those.

Comment: Yeah you're absolutely right, sorry for that.

Comment: Might be a bit off topic, but it seems you'd benefit from making the `deletePost` method a static one. That way you would not have to create an instance of the `Post` class when you want to delete a post, which makes more sense semantically as well as logically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your request is wrong, you should not be sending json if you expect to use the $_POST super global. Send it as regular url encoded form data

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/deletePost.php", 
        type: "POST",             
        data: {postDeleteID: postDeleteID},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {

        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh, you're right. I changed it, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I forgot to take out the `preocessData: false`, try now

Comment: Without the processData: false I get the following response:


    SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at n.parseJSON (http://localhost/imdstagram/public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:6401)
    at Ab (http://localhost/imdstagram/public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:8347)
    at z (http://localhost/imdstagram/public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:11804)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost/imdstagram/public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:15680)

Comment: That looks like you have html in you response.

Comment: Thanks, I'll continue looking for the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Try to change the dataType to 'text' and contentType to 'application/json'

Answer (score 1):

You are "deleting" the post twice.

Remove this line: `$post->deletePost($deletePostID);`

Comment: Thanks for that, deleted the line.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very strange problem within frameworks and PHP in general, in your controller just:

```
echo(json_encode($status));
```

Has worked for me ..